# Laravel replicate multiple rows didn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, replicate

I want to replicate multiple relational rows to the same table with the diff job id.
But it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
$parentJobUnits = Unit::where('job_id',$jobId)->get();  //may be single or multiple rows for units.

$JobCopy = $job->replicate()->save();    //main job copied for new units.

$partsCopy = array_map(function(Unit $unit) use($JobCopy)
{

     $newUnit = $unit->replicate();
     $newUnit->job_id = $JobCopy->id;
     return $newUnit->save();

}, $parentJobUnits);
```

The above code is not working for multiple row replication.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `save` method which causes a true return and not the copied record

correct: `$job->replicate();`
incorrect: `$job->replicate()->save();`

otherwise I'd do something like...

```
$parentJobUnits = Unit::where('job_id',$jobId)->get();

foreach($parentJobUnits as $unit)
{
    $unit->replicate()->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CollageData= Collage::where('student_id',$student_id)->get();
foreach($CollageData as $key => $collage )
   {     
      $collage->replicate()->save();
     
   }
```

This Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

`replicate()` function does not work on `get()` function. It only works with `find()` function.

```
$parentJobUnits = Unit::where('job_id',$jobId)->get();

foreach($parentJobUnits as $key => $value)
{
    $new_unit = Unit::find($value->id)->replicate(); // $value->id is your primary key
    $new_unit->save();
}
```

It will replicate the multiple rows.